# CSS3 -webkit different from vista - windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, css

-webkit transform isn't working on chrome on vista. On windows 7 in chrome is seems fine?
More specific is this: (not working on vista chrome):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: I've drilled it down to 2 overlapping absolute divs. One div has rotateY(180) backface-visibility:hidden. In chrome vista this one div seems to be above the front div causing it to cover it.

Comment: z-ordering is buggy in some chrome versions - try adding preserve-3D - sometimes this works. Also, you need to post a code sample or fiddle if you want people to help you debug "not working" could describe a pretty wide error case

Answer (score 0):

I answered on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684522/backface-visibilityhidden-bug-in-chrome/15248243#15248243)

So try :

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I hope that this will help you.