# backface-visibility:hidden bug in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I've found a bug in Chrome on windows Vista: CSS3 backface-visibility:hidden doesn't work. 
Here is an example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/TYuL3/)

This works fine on chrome in windows 7 and mac, but on chrome vista the backface is not hidden.

Anyone have any clues?

```
webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: Here is a the same issue with no fix :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455502/webkit-backface-visibility-not-working

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and have yet to find a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have now fixed the same problem with Chrome v75.0 when having an element and its child tags (p, img) with

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Chrome displays only the content of the children.
I use a jQuery plugin to flip some content. I fixed it by using

```
.not('p, img, br, strong')
```

to avoid to add the backface-visibility on childs.

Maybe it's like double hidden means show?! like in math - and - is + :-)

Comment: - and - = - || - times - = + ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, where "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden" was actually needed and what worked for me was to first set it to "visible" and then "hidden".

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing similar issue try adding following styles:

`-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`