# CSS3 transition / transformation (Card flip effect) failed in chrome 26

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have been trying to implement the card flip effect with css3 taking Flesky website as reference : http://fleksy.com/  
 Looking at the "Flesky has appeared in the press "section, the flipping effect works like a charm in my office Chrome (ver 26.0.1410.64 m, Win7 ) , however when viewing it using home Chrome (exactly same version, Vista) it was totally screwed up like this -> http://snag.gy/t5dkH.jpg.

Any idea of what's going on? I need to implement a similar flipping effect and still got no answer googling around. 
 Or anyone know is there any alternative solutions i can try?

Comment: I would say that `backface-visiblity: hidden` is not supported

Comment: @Raffael So does it mean even with the most updated Chrome on different machines there will still be variations in support of css3 properties? If so it is really a head-scratching issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684522/backface-visibilityhidden-bug-in-chrome   seems to be your question. Try the answer given

Comment: Thanks @Raffael I am gonna test it out.